# Set the Campaign Source by using a custom querystring parameter value

Tags: google-analytics

Lets say I have a partner that provides traffic to our website and that partner is identified by passing a *partner* querystring parameter with their name as the value of that parameter.

I'm trying to use an advanced view filter to set the Campaign Source.

My configuration currently is:

---

Field A -> Extract A : Request URI = partner=([^&]*)

Field B -> Extract B : -

Output To -> Constructor : Campaign Source = $A1

---

Field A Required = Yes

Field B Required = No

Override Output Field = Yes

Case Sensitive = No

---

An example url would be:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/?partner=someone
```

This configuration isn't setting the Campaign Source at all. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You missed the part where you are actually asking a question.

Comment: Got so carried away with explaining the issue that I forgot the question part. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to override source,medium and campaign name with three subsequent filters (the reason I think that is a) that with utm parameters these are the three mandatory ones and I assumed with filters it would work the same way and b) I just tested this and it worked).

Comment: Can't believe I missed this. Thanks!