# Search and Replace a View Filter: utm doesn't work?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to create some utm tagging transforming a custom parameter. So:

1. I created a new filter in View, selected custom/Search and Replace
2. Filter field = Request URI, Search string = `myparam=123`, Replace string = `utm_source=mysource&utm_medium=mymedium&utm_campaign=mycampaign`

So far it looks like it worked, I checked in Realtime/Content and the url I visited in my browser (`www.example.com/test.html?myparam=123`) showed as `test.html?utm_source=mysource&utm_medium=mymedium&utm_campaign=mycampaign`

Good!

Then I added a second filter, Include Campaign Source = mysource and... it didn't work!

I could spot requests when I visited `www.example.com/test.html?utm_source=mysource&utm_medium=mymedium&utm_campaign=mycampaign` but not when I visited `www.example.com/test.html?myparam=123`

It looks like utm tagging are treated in some "special" way. Does it make any sense?

Can you confirm the above? Any workaround to transform custom parameters into standard utm without modifying the web site?

Comment: This seems to cover the same ground: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193632/set-the-campaign-source-by-using-a-custom-querystring-parameter-value/22199285#22199285

Comment: Eike, thanks, it works, nice workaround!